# Invalid <Link> with <a> child error when fetching Wordpress posts via GraphQL in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, wordpress, next.js

I am trying to fetch Wordpress posts via graphql in my Next.js application, using the git repository "https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-wordpress".

I am getting the following error: "Error: Invalid  with  child. Please remove  or use .

[image: Invalid with child]

Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-new-link-with-extra-anchor This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window."

I am not sure what is causing this error or how to fix it. Could someone please help me understand what is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Next.js 13, Link renders as a, so attempting to use < a > as a child is invalid.

Comment: how can i fix this?